# upon loading my app in Heroku,Ive noticed that my images and borders have slightly increased in size.Why is that?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have My app running on Localhost and Heroku, Side by side. Image size and border size have increased and in some cases cause the image to be larger than than containing border, in Heroku . Any ideas to fix it ?

Comment: have you tried to clear the cache in one or both (in case that's the only difference) ?  Otherwise... it's going to be almost impossible for us to diagnose what "might" be wrong without some actual code, some screenshots, you checking if the source-code is identical etc etc... also - don't put code/more-info in comments, edit your question and add any relevant info there.

Comment: Try inspecting elements on both pages side by side, also check if there are any errors in your browser console

Comment: Can you post any screenshots & code snippets? Was going to write an answer, but I feel it will be better to see the "evidence" first

Comment: Thanks guys for the input. the image issue was fixed. that specific page that i had the app opened on, was zoomed in 1x and caused the error.